# How to add my application to quick launch Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-unity, quicklaunch

I write  java application and get the jar file, it work from command line

```
java -jar program.jar
```

I want to write installer program to put my application in Unity Launcher (quicklaunch) in Ubuntu.

can anyone give my how can I start?

Comment: Using the same method as you would for any executable command.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015892/installer-packager-for-a-java-application-for-ubuntu-and-suse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a simple **.desktop** file  in ~/.local/share/applications/

`vim ~/.local/share/applications/application_name.desktop`

add these entries to file

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Name= your application name
>   Comment=
>   Exec=java -jar program.jar
>   Icon=/path/to/icon
>   Terminal=false
>   Type=Application
>   StartupNotify=true

you will need to log off and back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: I execute chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/application_name.desktop and i don't need to log off